# Site works in IE8, FF, Chrome but shows "connection error" in IE7

Tags: web, internet-explorer-7

My site is showing a "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error in the browser when I visit it in IE7 but every other browser is fine.

I have tried from multiple machines and it works fine in IE8 Compatibility mode.

When I visit it in FF, the error console shows.

```
Error: Permission denied for <http://ad.uk.doubleclick.net> to call method Location.toString on <http://www.MYDOMAIN.com>.
```

I am not sure if this is related??? I am positive this is not a browser setting error as it is on any IE7.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

*Looks* like the doubleclick advertising is trying to do cross-domain scripting. Firefox is failing gracefully (and so is IE8, probably), whereas IE7 is giving up.

Comment: I did think it was something like that but surely double click would not do cross-domain scripting without it affecting many people.

Comment: try removing the advertising. If it goes away, then you have your answer. If not, then it's back to the drawing board